# How to view many to many tables on side by side column

Tags: php, mysql, view, many-to-many

I have table which is called as 'kelas'.

```
|id_kelas|nama_kelas|
```

I have table Sesi

```
|id_sesi|nama_sesi|
```

and I have another table which is sesikelas

```
|id_kelas|id_sesi|
```

many to many relation is there between kelas to sesi, what I want with PHP programming is that to show/view value of sesi on sesikelas side by side another on 2 colum.

example

```
|id_kelas|nama_kelas|session1|session2|
|01      |nama_kelas|id_sesi |id_sesi |
```

sesion1 or session2 come from the value on the table sesikelas.
the problem is, I want to combine the the id_sesi which is in equal to certain id_kelas. not one by one in a row, but if there is two record of id_kelas on table sesikelas will be display side by side.

Can anyone help me with php, how to view them exactly like in picture?

my PHP, but doesn't work properly.
I use mysql database, here is my php code.

```
$cls=mysql_query("select k.id_kelas,nama_kelas, sk.id_sesi,sesi from kelas k left join sesikelas sk on k.id_kelas=sk.id_kelas left join sesi on sk.id_sesi=sesi.id_sesi order by k.id_kelas");
while($fr = mysql_fetch_array($cls))
  {
  if ($temp2!=$fr['id_kelas'])
    {
      echo "<tr><td class='idclass'>".$fr['id_kelas']."</td>";
      echo "<td class='namecell'>".$fr['nama_kelas']."</td>";
      if(isset($fr['sesi']))
        {
            $x=mb_substr($fr['sesi'],0,1);
             echo "<td class='ses1cell'>".$hari[$x]." (".mb_substr($fr['sesi'],1,2).".".mb_substr($fr['sesi'],3,2)."-".mb_substr($fr['sesi'],5,2).".".mb_substr($fr['sesi'],7,2).")</td>";
        } else {
        echo "<td class='ses1cell'>Not set</td>";
        }
    $temp='skip';
    }  else {
    $temp='session2';
    }

    if (($temp=='session2'))
        {
        if(isset($fr['sesi']))
            {
            $x=mb_substr($fr['sesi'],0,1);
            echo "<td class='ses2cell'>".$hari[$x]." (".mb_substr($fr['sesi'],1,2).".".mb_substr($fr['sesi'],3,2)."-".mb_substr($fr['sesi'],5,2).".".mb_substr($fr['sesi'],7,2).")</td>";
            }else{echo "<td class='ses2cell'>Not set</td>";}
        echo "<td align='right'><a class='edit' href='#' onClick='Edit($(this))'>Edit</a> |
        <a class='delete' href='#' onClick='DeleteData($(this))'>Delete</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $temp='skip';
        }

    if (($temp=='skip') and ($temp2==$fr['id_kelas']))
    {   if ($temp2==$fr['id_kelas']){
        echo "<td class='ses2cell'>Not ff set</td>";}
        echo "<td align='right'><a class='edit' href='#' onClick='Edit($(this))'>Edit</a> |
        <a class='delete' href='#' onClick='DeleteData($(this))'>Delete</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    }
        $temp2=$fr['id_kelas'];
  }
```

Comment: Consider to provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: It sounds like you want a "pivot", which turns rows into columns. But usually there's another column value that is used as the name of the new column. For instance, if you have a table that has columns `month` and `sales`, and you want a result where each month is a different column.

Comment: What if there are more than two matching rows in sesikelas? Do you need them to be in separate columns, or could you use `GROUP_CONCAT` to get all the matching `id_sesi`. Also, it doesn't look like you're using anything from the `sesi` table, why is it in the join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, but I suspect this is what you want:

```
SELECT k.id_kelas, k.nama_kelas, s.session1, s.session2
FROM kelas k
JOIN sesikelas sk ON k.id_kelas = sk.id_kelas
JOIN sesi s ON s.id_sesi = sk.id_sesi
```

This is the normal way to join two tables using an intermediate relation table.

Comment: sesi table only have two columns = id_sesi and sesi, but I want sesi being shown twice if any two record exist.

Answer (score 0):

as you did not mention which database you are using, mysql or others. i assume you are using mysql.

```
<?php

  $con=mysqli_connect("host","user","passw”,"db”) ;
  $query=“select k.id_kelas, k.nama_kelas, session1,session2 
          from kelas k  inner join sesikelas sk 
          on sk.id_kelas=k.id_kelas “; 

  $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

  echo "<table>
  <tr>
  <th>id_kelas</th>
  <th>nama_kelas</th>
  <th>session1</th>
  <th>session2</th>
  </tr>";

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id_kelas'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['mama_kelas'] . "</td>”;
    echo "<td>" . $row['session1'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['session2'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";

  mysqli_close($con);
```

?>